# Differential equation $(y')^3+y^3-yy'=0?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, contest-math, physics, statistical-mechanics

How to solve differential equation $$(y')^3+y^3-yy'=0?$$ 
I tried parametrization $y'=p$, Laplace transformation...

After a while, I have solved it by help of WolframAlpha...

And idea is to divide with $y^3$, and further on it is easy.

But now, I'm interested if this differential equation has origins in statistical 
physics?
Any help or hint is welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Laplace transformation???? That works only on linear differential equations.  This one is not linear.  Parameterization $y'=p$ ... this works if you solve a cubic equation, then integrate.  Too messy to be of any use.

Comment: I think a closed form is not possible.

Comment: @GEdgar I know these steps where stupid, but I'm only a beginner.

Comment: @Moo I got $\frac{dt}{\sqrt[3]{e^{(-t)}-1}}=dy$ in final step and WA says the solution is hypergeometric function F1. This is my first time to see this function. To get final step you should substitute $\ln{y}$ with $t$.

Comment: @Moo [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+dt%2F%28e%5E%28-t%29-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29]